# Spritkit Added the node in the scene but not moving?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I wanted to create the background with few clouds moving from right to left.But when i ran this i can only see the clouds created on the background but they are not moving.

I have following class to create the clouds then add them in the scene. the last function moveBGcloud() will move clouds from right to left.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

import SpriteKit
class BGCloud :SKSpriteNode{

    private func shuffle(cloudsArray: [SKSpriteNode]) -> [SKSpriteNode] {

        var shuffledArray = cloudsArray;

        for i in 0..<shuffledArray.count {
            let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(shuffledArray.count - i))) + i;
            if i == j {continue}
            swap(&shuffledArray[i], &shuffledArray[j]);
        }

        return shuffledArray;
    }

    private func randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: CGFloat, secondNum: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * abs(firstNum - secondNum) + min(firstNum, secondNum);
    }

    func createClouds() -> [SKSpriteNode] {
        var clouds = [SKSpriteNode]();

            let cloud1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud 1");
            cloud1.name = "BGCloud1";
            let cloud2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud 2");
            cloud2.name = "BGCloud2";
            let cloud3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud 3");
            cloud3.name = "BGCloud3"
            let darkCloud = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Dark Cloud");
            darkCloud.name = "BGDarkCloud";

            cloud1.xScale = 0.3;
            cloud1.yScale = 0.3;

            cloud2.xScale = 0.4;
            cloud2.yScale = 0.4;

            cloud3.xScale = 0.5;
            cloud3.yScale = 0.5;

            darkCloud.xScale = 0.2;
            darkCloud.yScale = 0.2;


            clouds.append(cloud1);
            clouds.append(cloud2);
            clouds.append(cloud3);
            clouds.append(darkCloud);

        clouds = shuffle(cloudsArray: clouds);

        return clouds;
    }

    func arrangeBGCloudsInScene(scene: SKScene, minX: CGFloat, maxX: CGFloat,minY: CGFloat, maxY: CGFloat,speed:CGFloat) {

        var clouds = createClouds();

        for i in 0..<clouds.count {

            var randomX = CGFloat();
            var randomY = CGFloat();

            randomX = randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: minX, secondNum: maxX);
            randomY = randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: minY, secondNum: maxY);


            clouds[i].position = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: randomY);
            clouds[i].zPosition = 2;


            scene.addChild(clouds[i]);

        }

    }

    func moveBGcloud( speed:CGFloat){

        let cloudSpeed = speed
        self.position.x -= cloudSpeed

        print("postion",self.position.x)


        if self.position.x < -324 {
            self.position.x = 332

        }

    }

}
```

Then in the GameplayScene Class: (Back ground scene class)

I added instance of BGCloud class

```
    private var cloud1: BGCloud?
    private var cloud2: BGCloud?
    private var cloud3: BGCloud?
    private var darkCloud:BGCloud?

    private let BGCloud1Speed = 0.5
    private let BGCloud2Speed = 0.7
    private let BGCloud3Speed = 0.8
```

Then added function   BGCloudController.arrangeBGCloudsInScene to initialize the background

```
private func initializeGame() {

    BGCloudController.arrangeBGCloudsInScene(scene: self.scene!, minX: minX, maxX: maxX, minY: minY, maxY: maxY, speed: CGFloat(BGCloud1Speed))
    getBackgrounds();

}
```

Get the clouds from scene:

```
private func getBackgrounds() {

    cloud1 = self.childNode(withName: "BGCloud1") as? BGCloud!
    cloud2 = self.childNode(withName: "BGCloud2") as? BGCloud!
    cloud3 = self.childNode(withName: "BGCloud3") as? BGCloud!

}
```

The added CreateBGClouds function to move the background clouds from right to left in update function

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    createBGClouds()    

}



private func createBGClouds(){       

    cloud1?.moveBGcloud(speed: CGFloat(BGCloud1Speed))    //only add cloud1 for testing    
    print("function called")

}
```

When i ran the game i can see the four background clouds were randomly on the scene but they are not moving. seems like

moveBGcloud() function in BGCloud class was not get called. The Cloud1,2,3 are nil not get the value.Why? Also i did not use scene editor.

Could you help me to check what is the problem or anything i missed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: it looks like in the moveBGcloud method that you are changing self.position.x instead of the x position of the cloud, I imagine you would want to pass in your cloud as a parameter to that method so that it can change the x position of the cloud.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you calling your `moveBGCloud` method in `update(_:currentTime)` ? I think that's definitely a first step you want to take

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog not really. `moveBGcloud` is an instance method of the `BGCloud` class!?!

Comment: I think the issue was cloud1 = self.childNode(withName: "BGCloud1") as? BGCloud!  after this line of code the Cloud1,2,3 still nil seems like they didn't find the cloud sprit node named "BGCloud1" 2,3.... but in createClouds() in BGCloud class i already name cloud as  "BGCloud1" 2,3. The mopveBGcloud method was never get called...  Why?

Comment: @Pierce Yes, i did called moveBGCloud method in update function.  The createBGclouds() method inside of update function calls moveBGCloud

Comment: try an action instead, SKAction.moveBy(......

Comment: It should work (although I'd say you'd be better off using animations). Could you tidy up the code and post the classes in full? Could `cloud1`variable not being set somehow? Also, how can you have two `BGCloud`classes?

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing Sorry you are right. i changed the original post my mistake there should be only one BGCloud class..  Cloud1 currently has no value , the value for Cloud1 is nil dont know why. Also what animations do you mean?

Comment: OK, where is `getBackgrounds()` called from? It looks like it's just hanging in the air. It would help if you can take a little time to paste the code in properly. As it is code isn't making complete sense and trying to guess what the actual code is, isn't that much fun. (By animation, I meant using [running actions on nodes using SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction))

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing thank you very much for your time. The getBackgrounds() is inside of init method sorry another type error.....  I am thinking the issue is cloud1 = self.childNode(withName: "BGCloud1") as? BGCloud! cant find the name "BGCloud1" thats why the cloud1 is nil. I tried to print the value of cloud1.name in the BGCloud class and the value is "optional("BGClodu1")" not BGCloud1. but i am not sure is it cause the issue and how to unwrap it.

Comment: Sounds like it. Where are you calling [addChild()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483054-addchild) to add your clouds to the scene? If you aren't adding them that might be the reason `childNode(withName:)` is returning `nil`

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing  scene.addChild(clouds[i]) in BGCloud class to add the clouds to the scene also i can see the clouds are on the scene but   just not moving.....

Comment: OK, missed that. I think I'm slowly understanding it. `cloud1` is defined as `BGCloud` but when created it is created as `SKSpriteNode` in 'createClouds()' so I think that is why your casting (i.e. `as? BGCloud!`) is not working.. try changing the assignment in `func createClouds()` to something like `let cloud1 = BGCloud(imageNamed: "Cloud 1")`.. let me know if that works

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing Now its working perfectly. all the cloud can move . I am really appreciated your time and help!!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked finally :)

Answer (score 0):

As we figured out in the comments above there is kind of a typo in cloud instantiation.

Changing the assignments in `func createClouds()` to `BGCloud` fixes the issue:

```
    let cloud1 = BGCloud(imageNamed: "Cloud 1");
    cloud1.name = "BGCloud1";
    let cloud2 = BGCloud(imageNamed: "Cloud 2");
    cloud2.name = "BGCloud2";
    let cloud3 = BGCloud(imageNamed: "Cloud 3");
    cloud3.name = "BGCloud3"
```